# How to download link with unicode using wget?

Tags: wget, unicode

Sometimes a link has unicode characters in it, such as [http://www.example.com/файл.zip](http://www.example.com/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB.zip)

If you point your browser to it, it will properly prompt you to download the file as файл.zip. But if you try to do it with `wget`, the file comes with a mix of ?, percent encoding (like %D0%BB) and the `(invalid encoding)` string  after the filename.

What parameters can I add to wget, or any other command line tricks, so that it behaves as Chrome and Firefox and saves the file exactly as specified in the rendered link - in this case, as файл.zip?

The solution should work without having to explicitly write it in the command, so an explicit `wget -O файл.zip http://www.example.com/файл.zip` is not a good solution.

I realize that as soon as you run `wget http://www.example.com/файл.zip` it tries to retrieve http://www.example.com/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB.zip, that is, it converts the link to percent encoding, which may be the reason why it saves it doesn't render the filename "properly".

I posted a [somewhat related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078628/how-can-i-render-percent-encoding-in-command-line), whose answer may or may not be of help to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use curl instead, as follow

```
curl -O http://www.example.com/файл.zip
```

It will save it to файл.zip.

Answer (score 23):

For wget, you can use:

```
wget http://www.example.com/файл.zip --restrict-file-names=nocontrol
```

if your system can handle UTF-8 or other encoding properly.

Finally, if you still have those % symbols left in your downloaded file, you can use Python module `urllib.unquote(filename)` that will replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.

Comment: This should be marked as accepted answer, If the combination of this and everything else people do with wget(e.g. downloading recursively) could be done in curl OP and probably everyone else would have done it already.

Comment: Can be useful also `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol`  if file link is not final.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to solve this issue with `wget` but could successfully transfer the files with [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to the one posted by [Balaji Purushotham](https://askubuntu.com/a/250127/953371).

I had to add `.parse` to get this working in python:

```
import wget
wget.download(urllib.parse.unquote(url), destination_file)
```